# Two versions of fluentd fighting over port in my cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Somehow, I have 2 versions of fluentd running in my cluster:

[image]

They end up fighting over the same port, they just keep cranking away, trying to start up on that port, and it saturates all the CPU in the cluster.

`unexpected error error_class=Errno::EADDRINUSE error="Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:24231`
`/opt/google-fluentd/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:201:in 'bind'`

I've tried deleting the daemon sets and deployments, they just keep coming back. Also tried ssh'ing into the machines and killing the process on that port. Nothing seems to work.

Obviously, I only want one version of fluentd to run (and I'm not even sure which one).

Comment: is this on a managed GKE cluster?

Comment: Is a new cluster in GKE? Did you upgrade it recently? Or since when it is happen?

Comment: This is a managed GKE cluster, it is not new.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it. I went to GCP dashboard cluster edit page, `Kubernetes Engine Monitoring` dropdown **was blank**. It seems not even the dropdown could decide what to display here.

It seems the automated agent, or whatever, seriously messed up here, and had 2 versions of the logging and monitoring system running, fighting over a port, and crushing the CPU on every machine in the cluster. On top of that, I couldn't delete the daemon sets, pods, or deployments. It seems Google treats these as special somehow, maybe with some kind of automated agent, I don't know.

From the dropdown, I just selected `System and workload logging and monitoring`, saved, and it applied the changes.

Everything looking good so far, but this whole event has me worried, I didn't do anything. This just....happened.

This is a dev cluster, but if it was a production cluster...

Comment: Great you solve the issue and weird behavior... Maybe if you facing something in the same way next time, try to open a issue on Google issue platorm.